# Is there a way to specify abstract functions which take in values for __init__

Tags: python, django, django-models, abstract-class, django-rest-framework

I was not sure how to specify this completely in the title, so please forgive me. Essentially, I want to define a method a get_object() method, like the one described here

http://django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views.html#rewriting-our-api-using-class-based-views

but in an abstract manner. For example, let's say I want to extend APIView as such

```
class BetterAPIView(APIView):
    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return ***Class name***.objects.get(pk=pk)
        catch:
            raise Http404
```

so that when I define a view, there is an automatic definition for this get_object method. For example, if my view for a blog post is

```
class BlogDetail(BetterAPIView):

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        Post = Post.get_object(pk)
```

I want the get_object method to automatically know that Post.get_object(pk) implies that I want to get an object from the Post Model, with the pk given in the get method. I am guessing that maybe BlogDetail should have some sort of **init** method which defines how to handle the name of the model I am using, but I'm not too sure how this would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about doing what the generic Django class-based-views do and have a `model` property that you need to set?

```
class BetterAPIView(APIView):
    model = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.model is None:
            raise SomeSortOfConfigurationException
        super(BetterAPIView, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return self.model.objects.get(pk=pk)
        catch:
            raise Http404
```

And now:

```
class BlogDetail(BetterAPIView):
    model = Post

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        post = self.get_object(pk)
```

Of course, this is a rough example, you would want to make it more robust...